# How do I display some no results text in a view if the views results are aggregated?

Tags: 7, views

I have created a view block that displays the number of users a separate user has flagged. I did this by using the "Use aggregation" option in the advanced drop down. I have a UID field that I have grouped by count, and in the no results configuration I have written "0". For some reason when I go and print out my view, if there are no results, it won't display anything and I am wondering why.

Comment: I figured it out. Instead of configuring the no results display on the UID field, I had to configure it in the no results display of the view itself.

Comment: Well done! You can add that as an answer and mark it as accepted so that others know the state of the question.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. Instead of configuring the no results display on the UID field, I had to configure it in the no results display of the view itself.